# Could you please convert this V1 code part to V5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's the code part I'm struggling with:

```
bcolor = iff( val > 0, 
            iff( val > nz(val[1]), lime, green),
            iff( val < nz(val[1]), red, maroon))
```

The reason of my confusion is that I don't get its logic because line #3 and line #2 are the ELSE case of each other (excepting the `=` case). This is why I failed to make a V5 compliant form for it.

This code is from a working indicator, from the public library.

Answer (score 1):

It is nested if-else statements.

```
iff(condition, then, _else)
```

So, you can write the same expression as:

```
bcolor = if (val > 0)
    if (val > nz(val[1]))
        lime
    else
        green
else
    if (val < nz(val[1])
        red
    else
        maroon
```

Comment: :) It was still a V1 but you helped me to understand the code so I could convert it to V5. Posted the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
bcolor = val > 0 ? (val > nz(val[1]) ? color.lime : color.green) : (val < nz(val[1]) ? color.red : color.maroon)
```

or wrapped:

```
bcolor = val > 0 ? 
    (val > nz(val[1]) ? color.lime : color.green) : 
    (val < nz(val[1]) ? color.red : color.maroon)
```